# ReactJS, getdata from parent of child without and envent from child

Tags: reactjs

I have a container component (called "App") connected with Redux to the store. This component renders 2 (among others) components called "Tab" and "SaveButton". What "SaveButton" does is, onClick, it calls to a `this.handleSave(this.state.data)` function that pass as parameter some `data` that comes from `state`. But the other component "Tab" is setting locally all it's data. The big picture would be this:

[App.js]

```
//imports, constructor, etc...

this.handleSave = data => {
    const { saveAction } = this.props
    saveAction(this.state.data)
}

render() {
    return(<>
        <Tab someProps>

        <Other components that has handles functions that sets data on this.state.data>

        <SaveButton onClick={this.handleSave}>
    </>)
}
```

[Tab.js]

```
//imports, contructor, etc...

A lot of `onClick={this.handleChange}` functions that sets states locally from Inputs, selects, radio buttons, etc.
```

So how can I retrieve the data from `<Tab>` and set it together with `this.state.data` in order to save the data that comes from `<Other components>` and `<Tab>` too?

EDIT: What I tried was to pass as props from parent to child a functio like this:

```
<App getData={this.getData} >
```

but now where can I use that prop in child? the `onClick` that triggers the save function event is in the parent, not in the child, so I don't know how could I use that prop in the child. I tried when some state changes, like in componentDidUpdate, but that results in a loop. I was thinking to use that prop on each handleChange of the  component, but I wonder if there's a better solution that retrieves in one action all the state from

Comment: As I understand, you want to get the new state in App component as soon as the state in Tab component changes. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, because I could click on Save button at any time, then there I have to use the data from Tab

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in one of two ways:

1: Make the `Tab` component a 'controlled' component where `App` stores the state used in `Tab` and passes the values and change handlers down to `Tab`, i.e.:

```
this.onTabValueChange = (tabValue) => {
  this.setState({
    tabValue,
  });
}
...
render() {
  <Tab
    tabValue={this.state.tabValue}
    onTabValueChange={this.onValueAChange}
  />
}
...
```

2: Connect the `Tab` component to redux - either through redux's connect or by passing down set action from `App`.

Essentially, `App` needs access to the values in `Tab` so it should either own them as a parent, or redux should own them and share them between `App` and `Tab` outside of the tree.